# Cones made by subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, projection

Let $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $k$-dimensional subspace and $c>0$. We denote by $P$ and $Q$, respectively, the orthogonal projection on $V$ and $V^{\perp}$. And we denote by $C(V,c)$ the set $\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid |Q(x)| \le c |P(x)| \}$. Now we fix a $c>0$. How is the following statement showed?

There exists a finite collection of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces $\{ V_1, \dots, V_N\}$ such that for every $k$-dimensional linear subspace $V$ we have $C(V,c)\subset C(V_m, 2c)$ for some $V_m$.

Comment: What progress have you made? Can you prove it when $k=1$? or $k=2$?

Comment: @angryavian I tried it by using the compactness, but I couldn't do it even if $k=1$....

Comment: For $k=1$, you can represent a cone by its intersection with the unit sphere $\{x : |x| = 1\}$ (this intersection will look like a spherical cap). Then I think if you cover the sphere with sufficiently many points, and let these points specify the axis of your cones $C(V_m, 2c)$, then the axis for an arbitrary cone $C(V,c)$ will be close enough to the axis of another cone $C(V_m, 2c)$ to have $C(V,c) \subseteq C(V_m 2c)$.

Comment: @angryavian you should consider writing that out as an answer

Comment: @angryavian How do you take “sufficiently many points” on the sphere?